# Firebase pod update not updating

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

- Xcode version: 11.2.1
- Pod version: 1.8.4

Below is my pod file:

[image]

So I run command

```
pod update
```

pod is not updated at all

**Below is detail info of my terminal:**
[image]

As you can see, everything related to firebase is not updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `pod 'Firebase', '6.13.0'` to the Podfile.

Or delete the last four pods listed there.

Without it, there's not enough information in the Podfile to do the right thing.  Because the latest Firestore requires an old version of gRPC-C++, CocoaPods must either install the latest Firestore with an old gRPC-C++ or the latest gRPC-C++ with a version of Firestore that didn't require it.

The Podfile should be explicit about which latest version it wants.

Also, if the app does not directly require a certain pod(gRPC-C++?), it should not be in the Podfile so that the dependency that it does need (Firestore), can choose the proper transitive dependency.

Comment: Hi @Paul, think you for your reply, I want to update gRPC-C++ to the latest version, so which version of Firestore I should choose ?

Comment: Firestore does not yet work with the latest gRPC-C++. You can track the progress of the integration at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/pull/4312

Comment: Got it, thanks, so I just removed the last four pods, then did pod update, Firebase and Firestore is updated the latest one, but there is a new issue occurs, could you pls take a look ? I created a new question for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59128847/xcode-grpc-core-error-openssl-grpc-ssl-h-file-not-found